# How many numbers between 1 and 1,000 (both inclusive) are divisible by at least one of the prime between 1 to 50? How can I find this?

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility, prime-factorization

I was trying to solve a compettive programming problem in which constraints are so high so I want to deduce a formula for it so that i could do it for other ranges as well.

Comment: You should know that when you have such a question dealing with ranges of **prime numbers** and such, there is usually no formula to deal with it.

Comment: That problem with high constraints wouldn't be from Project Euler or CodeChef by any chance? You know they have a rule against cheating? And [we have a policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31950/11619). On top of that, do you read the tag description at all, or do you pick them randomly. This question has nothing whatsoever to do with [tag:division-algebras].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $50^2>1000$, the only numbers in this range that aren't divisible are $1$ and the primes between $50$ and $1000$. So the answer is
$$1+\pi(1000)-\pi(50)=1+168-15=154.$$